# Showing bound for operator norm on $\mathcal{L}(L^p)$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $f \in L^p(0,\infty)$, and consider \begin{equation}F_f(x) = \frac{1}{x}  \int_0^x f(y) dy \end{equation} where $F:L^p(0,\infty) \rightarrow L^p(0,\infty)$, show that 
\begin{equation} \|F\| \leq \frac{p}{p-1} \end{equation}

I can come up with the denominator if I majorate the integral on $F$ by $\|f\|_p$ but i get stuck with $\int_0^\infty x^{-p}$ and this blows up.

I also tried using holder on $\int |f(y)|dy$ but couldn't get anywhere.

Any hints on how to majorate this norm?

Comment: Use Hardy's inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%27s_inequality